# What's the mean of "network i/o" in the protocol of Jmeter's startAgent.sh?

Tags: jmeter

After analysing Jmeter's startAgent.sh's protocol, I found when I send 

`b'metrics:cpu:\tmemory:\tnetwork i/o:\tdisks i/o:\tswap:\ttcp:\t\n'`

to the startAgent.sh, startAgent.sh will return me the server's data, which is about server's CPU, network IO, disks IO and so on. But when I use it in my test, I use startAgent.sh and ifstat to monitoring the network IO. The ifstat shows that the in and out io is 220KB/s, however startAgent.sh show that the net data is around 900000. What's the mean of the number 900000? Does it mean the network IO is 900KB/s? It is very confusing me a lot. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it by myself. Jmeter's network IO shows network card and loopback network IO. And ifstat shows only network card IO. So if I use ifstat -l, I will get the right result.